# Tensorflow batching Kotlin

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

So I have a list of images, and I want to load them as batches, is there anyone who could help me write a function that gets me from a list of images to an inputBuffer ?
Thank you

Comment: Try looping of the images. Have a look at your other question.

Comment: Hi @FirasSOLTANI, you can use tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory to batch list of images. Thank You.

Comment: I can't use that function because it's not available in TFLite